# Angular-cli how to put html content from index.html into app.component.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, universal-cli

I need to edit head tag from index.html... So it would be useful if I can insert content from index.html to my app.component....

Any solution for this?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: because of seo...

Comment: My point was  to explain more what do you want to achieve. I do not understand your Question completly

Comment: I want to change tags in head....

Comment: Change tags in runtime ?

Comment: Need to change on server side...

Comment: If you really need help, edit your question, paste some code, explain exactly what is your problem and what do you want to achieve!